# Manipulating a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

I have to manipulate a deeply nested hash (5 or six levels) in Ruby. For example, I need to swap the 3rd and 4th levels like so, from:

```
a[b][c][d][e] = []
```

to:

```
a[b][d][c][e]=  []
```

Can anyone point me to algorithms that will help me? I'm not lazy, just under a time constraint.

Comment: I don't understand. Is it that you don't know which two elements will need to be exchanged? Furthermore, does the hash really need to be so complex?

Comment: I do know which elements I want to exchange. I'm resorting this to build an XML file structure that is nested differently than the source hash.

Comment: @yock: Deeply nested hashes is something more common than we'd like... Often a symptom of poor design, indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am terribly tired, you'd get away with something like so:

```
result = Hash.new
a.each do |b, ab|
    result[b] ||= Hash.new
    ab.each do |c, abc|
        abc.each do |d, abcd|
            (result[b][d] ||= Hash.new)[c] = abcd
        end
    end
end
a = result
```

Now, I'm not saying this is the most efficient way of working it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since it came to light that you're parsing XML, I strongly suggest that you don't roll your own solution. [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) is one option for parsing XML in Ruby.

Comment: I'm not parsing it, I'm creating it from data.